# accessing variables one a button is entered in php

Tags: php

I have a kinda weird situation where I have to access a variable once the submit button is entered. here is the code which am working on...

```
echo '<form>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="report1" value="submit"></button>';
echo '<input type="text" name="inp1" id="inp1"></input>';
echo '<input type="text" name="inp2" id="inp2"></input>';
$ean = $_POST['inp1'] ;
$url = $_POST['inp2'] ;
if (isset($_POST['report'])) 
{
if ($ean=='0')
{
//do nothing 
} 
else
{
echo echo '<input type="submit" name="report2" value="submit"></button>';
}
}
if (isset($_POST['report2'])) 
{
$ean = "xyz";
echo $ean;
}
echo '</form>';
```

SO, here while clicking on the the Button name report2 I want to access the $ean and $url variables but its showing null means the variables are not storing the value input in the inp1 and inp2 input box...can any one please suggest me what to do.

Comment: give different values for submit buttons....

Comment: please create hidden fields and put them in value. Because only those fields which having some name attribute in the form will posted when button in the form is clicked. Also your code is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: `<input>...</button>` looks mismatched to me

Comment: @Drakes...<input>...</button> is working for me no problem yet....

Comment: Perhaps, but it makes us coders weep ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the help of the comments posted here I did the following trick and it works for me...

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="hidTitle" value="'.$ean.'" />';
```

and access this variable by `_POST['hidTitle']`

and it works for me